# how to upgrade phing 'stable' to phing 'trunk' to use SSHTask

Tags: deployment, ssh, web-deployment-project, phing

phing 2.4.1 (current stable version) doesn't have an SSH Task to do remote scripting.
In the current trunk version, there is a SSH Task that we would like to use.

How can I upgrade my current phing installation (2.4.1) to the latest build? Can I use pear for that without breaking my current phing install?

Or would it be better to download only the SSH Task and add that file manually to the stable phing install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a clean copy of the trunk from the repository:

```
svn export http://svn.phing.info/trunk phing
```

Or a working copy (so that you can eventually update it):

```
svn checkout http://svn.phing.info/trunk phing
```

and place it anywhere in your file system. The executable is under the bin folder, use that instead of the one in your current installation.

```
$ phing/bin/./phing -v
Phing DEV
```

Comment: yep, I got that far. I also see that the SshTask.php is already included in the stable release (but not documented). When running the SshTask in phing, I get the following: BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file [wrapped: To use SshTask, you need to install the SSH extension.]
Total time: 0.4119 seconds. How can I solve that?

Comment: You need to install the SSH2 extension for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php